# Upsert embedded object in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Given this Person collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f8e95a718bcv9c74da1e6511a"),
    "name" : "John",
    "hobbies" : [{
        "id" : 001,
        "name" : "reading",
        "location" : "home"
    },{
        "id" : 002,
        "name" : "sport",
        "location" : "outside"
    }]
}
```

and these new/edited Hobby objects:

```
{
    "name" : "walking",
    "location" : "outside"
}
```

and

```
{
    "id" : 001,
    "name" : "reading",
    "location" : "outside"
}
```

If I know the `Person` that I want to manage, what is be the best way to upsert embedded objects?

Currently my approach is to find the `Person` object, make the required modifications to it in my code, and then save it back to the DB. This works. But I'd like to simplify and reduce the number of round trips to the database.

Comment: Is `hobbies` an array?  What you're showing in the example looks like one but doesn't have the square brackets.

Comment: Hmmm, [this open feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340) seems to suggest this ability is not yet possible...

Comment: I think you're right.  You can use `$addToSet` to add an element only if it's missing, but you can't combine that with an update if it exists.

Comment: Upsert on an embedded document is not currently possible.  The [SERVER-340](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340) issue you pointed out would address this for a directly embedded document, but your case of updating an array of embedded documents would probably require more advanced manipulation ("upsert embedded document within array").